# Pandas df.describe doesn't work after adding new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a Pandas dataframe with 118 columns and I'd like to add a new column 'x119'. 
I tried using various methods which all seem to work like:

```
df = df.assign(x119=F))
```

or:

```
df.loc[:,'x119'] = F
```

The methods seem to add the column to the `df` dataframe but when I use:

```
df.describe()
```

I still get 118 columns. Has anyone encountered this situation? The column seem to exist when calling `df['x119']` but not shown in the description of `df.describe()`.

EDIT: The values of F are categorical with numeric values of 1,2,3. The column `'x119'` did not exist in df before and when I use `df2=df` and then `df2.decribe()` it works fine and I can see all columns.

Comment: It is categorical data with numeric labels: 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Case 1: all datatypes are numeric:

`df.describe()` works fine after `df.assign(..)` for numeric datatypes, here's a reproducible example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=list('AB'))
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> df["C"] = np.nan 
>>> df
   A  B   C
0  1  2 NaN
1  3  4 NaN
>>> df.describe()
              A         B    C
count  2.000000  2.000000  0.0
mean   2.000000  3.000000  NaN
std    1.414214  1.414214  NaN
min    1.000000  2.000000  NaN
25%    1.500000  2.500000  NaN
50%    2.000000  3.000000  NaN
75%    2.500000  3.500000  NaN
max    3.000000  4.000000  NaN
>>> df.assign(D=5)
   A  B   C  D
0  1  2 NaN  5
1  3  4 NaN  5
>>> df.describe()
              A         B    C
count  2.000000  2.000000  0.0
mean   2.000000  3.000000  NaN
std    1.414214  1.414214  NaN
min    1.000000  2.000000  NaN
25%    1.500000  2.500000  NaN
50%    2.000000  3.000000  NaN
75%    2.500000  3.500000  NaN
max    3.000000  4.000000  NaN
>>> df  = df.assign(D=5)
>>> df.describe()
              A         B    C    D
count  2.000000  2.000000  0.0  2.0
mean   2.000000  3.000000  NaN  5.0
std    1.414214  1.414214  NaN  0.0
min    1.000000  2.000000  NaN  5.0
25%    1.500000  2.500000  NaN  5.0
50%    2.000000  3.000000  NaN  5.0
75%    2.500000  3.500000  NaN  5.0
max    3.000000  4.000000  NaN  5.0
>>>
```

- Make sure you assign the result of df.assign back to df like df= df.assign(...)

---

### Case 2: mixed numeric and object datatypes:

For mixed object and numeric datatypes, you need to do `df.describe(include='all')` as mentioned in the *Notes* section from the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html):

> For mixed data types provided via a DataFrame, the default is to
>   return only an analysis of numeric columns. If include='all' is
>   provided as an option, the result will include a union of attributes
>   of each type.

```
>>> df["E"] = ['1','2']
>>> df
   A  B   C  D  E
0  1  2 NaN  5  1
1  3  4 NaN  5  2
>>> df.describe()
              A         B    C    D
count  2.000000  2.000000  0.0  2.0
mean   2.000000  3.000000  NaN  5.0
std    1.414214  1.414214  NaN  0.0
min    1.000000  2.000000  NaN  5.0
25%    1.500000  2.500000  NaN  5.0
50%    2.000000  3.000000  NaN  5.0
75%    2.500000  3.500000  NaN  5.0
max    3.000000  4.000000  NaN  5.0
>>> df
   A  B   C  D  E
0  1  2 NaN  5  1
1  3  4 NaN  5  2
>>>
```

so you need to call describe as follows:

```
>>> df.describe(include='all')
               A         B    C    D    E
count   2.000000  2.000000  0.0  2.0    2
unique       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN    2
top          NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN    2
freq         NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN    1
mean    2.000000  3.000000  NaN  5.0  NaN
std     1.414214  1.414214  NaN  0.0  NaN
min     1.000000  2.000000  NaN  5.0  NaN
25%     1.500000  2.500000  NaN  5.0  NaN
50%     2.000000  3.000000  NaN  5.0  NaN
75%     2.500000  3.500000  NaN  5.0  NaN
max     3.000000  4.000000  NaN  5.0  NaN
>>>
```

Comment: Unfortuately it is not empty. If I use: df2=df and then do df2.decribe() it works fine

Comment: Thank you! The solution was the  include='all' which included the categorical numeric data as well!

Comment: @AR_ yes that was it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think problem should be `x119` column was in df before, so only overwrite values.

You can check it by:

```
print (df['x119'])
```

Simpliest add new column is by:

```
print (len(df.columns))
df['x119'] = F
print (len(df.columns))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just edited my post to clarify.

Comment: Ok, if check lengt of columns, are always same?

Comment: Tried exactly what you suggested. got 117 and 118 respectively. This is so weird :/

Comment: And `print (len(df.columns))` before and after is same?

Comment: The length is not the same. It grows by 1 but the describe is uneffected

Comment: Ok, then what return `print (df['x119'].describe())` ?

Comment: It returns an error. Shouldn't I use df['x119'].describe() without the print?

Comment: If use `python 2` it is without `()`. What kind of error it return?

Comment: I didn't use  include='all' for categorical data. Thank you for your time!