# (Python/Pandas) Replaced strings with ints but df.describe() doesn't calculate those columns

Tags: python, pandas, replace, integer, describe

I am working on a project linking psychological battery exams to the chances patients will abuse prescription drugs. My original dataset looked like this:

```
ID Age Sex Neuro Aggro Agree Impulse Cocaine Crack ... Legal MJ
1   25  M   9      4     1      5      CL1    CL2  ...  CL1  CL3
2   28  F   4      5     5      8      CL0    CL1  ...  CL3  CL3
```

I figured it would be nice to just get rid of the CL's and just have the numbers, so I ran

```
df=df.replace('CL0', 0, regex= True)
```

So my dataset looked more like

```
ID Age Sex Neuro Aggro Agree Impulse Cocaine Crack ... Legal MJ
1   25  M   9      4     1      5      1       2  ...    1    3
2   28  F   4      5     5      8      0       1  ...    3    3
```

However, when I run df.describe(), it would only show the columns I didn't change. I checked for strings in my altered columns, but there weren't any. The values are all integers for each edited column. I then tried df.describe(include = 'all') as per [Pandas df.describe doesn't work after adding new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067785/pandas-df-describe-doesnt-work-after-adding-new-column), and the values for edited columns are there for count, unique, top, and freq, but all of the mathematical descriptors are null, such as average, Std Dev, etc.

What am I missing? How can I replace the values in the above columns with integers that the df.describe() will be able to perform the necessary math on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So I just realized that when I ran df.info(), these columns are still represented as objects. So I guess I need to make the columns run as integers.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer at [Pandas: convert dtype 'object' to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173813/pandas-convert-dtype-object-to-int)

Nii Nii Joshua's post helped the most:

```
df['col_name'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col_name'])
```

This is a better option

Answer (score 0):

```
file.csv
ID Age Sex Neuro Aggro Agree Impulse Cocaine Crack ... Legal MJ
1   25  M   9      4     1      5      CL1    CL2  ...  CL1  CL3
2   28  F   4      5     5      8      CL0    CL1  ...  CL3  CL3


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_csv("/content/file.csv")

df.head()

df.columns

coc={}
for i,v in enumerate(df['Cocaine'].unique(),1):
  coc[v]=i

cra={}
for i,v in enumerate(df['Crack'].unique(),1):
  cra[v]=i

print(cra)
print(coc)

df['Cocaine'].replace(coc,inplace=True)
df['Crack'].replace(cra,inplace=True)

df.head()

df.dtypes

df.describe()
```

output:

```
ID          int64
Age         int64
Sex        object
Neuro       int64
Aggro       int64
Agree       int64
Impulse     int64
Cocaine     int64
Crack       int64
dtype: object
```